# SAPGUI disable auto fill feature

Tags: sap

SAPGUI
How do you disable the auto fill feature in SAPGUI? When inserting information the system is automatically prepopulating information that the user must then erase.  We have already tried the procedure described in "How to disable the new SAP field auto-complete/enhanced search."

Answer (score 0):

Is the field defaulting to a value?  That's set by a parameter linked to the field on the screen and you would likely have to modify the screen to remove that.
If options appear as you type, that's the Local Data\History setting in the SAP GUI Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Check your user settings.  In your user profile there is a parameter ID table.  In that table, if the parameter ID for a field is entered with a value, that value will be populated into the field in any transaction, but then be overwritten by the user.  Another way fields get pre-populated is through field variables.  You may or may not have access to change any of these.  I would ask your SAP support resources.